# Is the nationality of Stacy hinted anywhere prior to this episode?

Tags: character, phineas-and-ferb

Stacy is one of the major characters in *Phineas and Ferb*. She is the best friend of Candace. While reading through her [wikia page](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Stacy_Hirano), I found out that she is a Japanese American. Her nationality is only mentioned in the special episode "[Summer belongs to you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phineas_and_Ferb:_Summer_Belongs_To_You!)". Phineas and Ferb visit her cousins in Tokyo.  Only mention about her native place and nationality is in the same episode when Stacy says

> Say Hi to Jeremy for me and hey you should stop by and see my cousins in Tokyo.

When it comes to Baljeet, it is mentioned several times that he is an Indian. Similarly, is there a specific mention *before this special episode* that Stacy is of Japanese origin i.e., by some song or a dialogue?

Comment: Her last name is Japanese, if that counts.

Comment: @Kitkat But, no one calls her by her Japanese name in the show. I came to know it only from external sources. Is her nationality hinted in the show itself?

Comment: For what it's worth, it doesn't seem to me like something the creators either tried to hide prior to that episode or retconned for that single episode.